# select only last record based on room, project and item

Tags: oracle, reporting-services

This is a hard one to describe, I apologize for the vague title.

I have an Oracle database and am using SSRS (Report Builder 3.0) to generate inventory reports. Each record in my inventory table contains reference to a room id and a project id and holds a count of each type of item in that room. New records are added only when an item count changes. Also, I do not know the room or project id's a priori, though they can be fetched from another table.

What I want is to create a report with month beginning and ending counts by room, project and item. I probably do not have an inventory record for either the first or last day of the month, so I need to get the count from the most recent inventory record.

If I had a way to do a "foreach unique (project + room + item)", I could get the last record for which the date is <= YYYY-MM-01 to get the beginning inventory and the last record for which the test is <= YYYY-MM- to get the ending inventory.

Is there a way to do this in Oracle + SSRS?

Comment: Is there a timestamp for each added record to the inventory table? Or any time related column?

Comment: Yes, there is a "validitydate" column which represents the date for which the count is valid. If this date is, say, 13 August 2015, then the "widgetcount" for that record is the number of widgets in the room on that day. Also, since the record exists, this means that this count is different from the previous day.